# Default tmp location

Tags: linux, disk-partitioning

How to change default tmp location in Ubuntu?

I am using Ubuntu for my applications. I have seen that many APIs store their tmp files in /tmp folder.

In my Ubuntu, total space assigned to root is hardly 4 GB. 
Which is why I have to keep cleaning the /tmp folder to avoid disk space error.

Can I change /tmp to some other partition and allocate more space to it ?

---

UPDATE:

I have considered resizing partitions, but I can not risk data loss. 
Also, I can not risk impacting other applications which might have some data in /tmp folder.

As of now, I am using shell script to clean it every 10 minutes.

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5503

Comment: *...I am using shell script to clean it every 10 minutes.*: that sounds dangerous. How do you avoid applications misbehaving because of missing temporary files?

Comment: In this case, I know which files I am cleaning and how they are generated. I also know impact of cleaning these files. So I am doing it safe way. But if I am able to Increase space OR point /tmp to a larger space, it will remove need to clean these files.

Answer (score 4):

Many applications look at the `TMPDIR` environment variable for the name of the temporary file directory, before defaulting to using `/tmp`. A simple *partial* solution to your problem (and possibly several others) could be to have a per-user temporary directory e.g. `/home/$USER/tmp` by setting the `TMPDIR` variable in the profile of each user.

That would move most temporary files to `/home`, with the added advantage that users would no longer be able to interfere with the temporary files of other users.

Answer (score 0):

in general, it is possible, but it can be pretty dangerous. Make yourself sure that your data are backed up. There are many tools how it can be done. You need some partition manager like `fdisk` (it is a command line), or graphical `GParted`

General advice: for your root `\` I'd recommend some 20GB (standard desktop app), for `\tmp` it depends on what kind of application you will use (resource-demanding, or just open office) some 1-2GB

Comment: How is that dangerous? And the OP already said, that `/`[sic!] is only 4G, I think (s)he thought about increasing that size already.

Comment: well, i understood the question like @Learn More found out that his partitions are not very well sized. Therefore I proposed to resize his(er) partitions. Dangerous - partition modification is always dangerous (lost of data). But maybe I didn't get the question correctly ...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible (at least in an easy way). Even if it would be, I would not advice that, because many programs/scripts use hardcoded *"/tmp"* so various errors may occur. However, you may try to link */tmp* to some other directory, it might do the trick (it's up to you to experiment, I did not try this myself).

Answer (score 0):

You can either change `/tmp` to a symlink or bind-mount it somewhere in your fstab.